# Dynamic select menu options with jQuery Uniform and JSF2

Tags: jquery, jsf, uniform

We have an application that uses JSF 2, OpenFaces, jQuery and the Uniform plugin.  There is a form that has a select box with options that are dynamically populated based on the value of another select box.  We are using the JSF 2 f:ajax tag to fire off the re-population of the select box.

Here is the box that fires the ajax call:

```
    <h:selectOneMenu id="applicant-employmentStatus-civilian"
                        value="#{membershipData.civilianEmploymentStatus}">
                        <f:selectItems value="#{lookup.civilianEmploymentOptions }"/>
                        <f:ajax event="change" 
                            render="applicant-eligibility-base applicant-eligibility-ship applicant-eligibility-govtAgency"
                            onevent="ajaxCallback"/>
                        <o:validateCustom clientFunction="return validateEligibilityField(input.id);"
                            summary=""
                            detail="#{msgs['errormesg.eligibility.employment']}" />
                    </h:selectOneMenu>
```

3 other select boxes are populated from this call.

The page also uses the Uniform plugin to decorate all the form inputs.  On the document.ready() function, the following is called to configure this:

```
$('select, input:text, input:radio').uniform();
```

The problem is that when the 3 select box are rendered after the Ajax call, they "lose" the decoration and become unusable in FF, Chrome, etc.  In IE, an un-formatted select box is placed over the old one.  I tried calling the uniform() function in the ajaxCallback function but it doesn't work.

Any help appreciated

Comment: it should work when you call it in the onevent function with a status of success. Can you post what you for the function ajaxCallback?

Answer (score 2):

I figured out the problem.

You need to call $.uniform.restore('select') before calling $('select').uniform().  Uniform restore removes all Uniform formatting and restores it to a "normal" select control.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ajaxCallback(e) {
        if(e.status == 'success') {
            $('select, input:text, input:radio').uniform();
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I tried doing this already.  It re-decorates the fields but when you click on the select box, nothing happens.

Comment: maybe the uniform plugin creates additional dom elements that are not part of the render. try changing render to render="@form". Does it work when you render everything?